# LWJGL Java App Only Launches By Terminal (Linux, potentially OS X)

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I have an application I've created using LWJGL with two main components: a game and an editor. When running the jar by eclipse or using `java -jar <jarname>.jar`, the application runs the LWJGL components just fine. However, whenever I just double click the .jar to run it, the LWJGL components will not run in the application, show no errors, they just literally do nothing.

I have all the libraries linked, before any LWJGL componenents are even called, I make sure to set the library path to the proper natives depending on your OS.

As to how the app is structured, I have one Jar file that runs a sort of mini launcher, allowing the user to select either game or engine. When game is selected, the button is depressed for a few seconds and the game's window never pops up. Again, running via command line produces no such issues.

My directory Structure is as follows
App.jar

|-lib

|----jars

|----natives

|-----------windows

|-----------macosx

|-----------linux

|-res

|-save

In the natives/windows or natives/macosx or natives/linux folders are the proper natives. in the jars folder is the LWJGL jars such as lwjgl-util.jar and lwjgl.jar, however Eclipse also compiles these jars into the launcher. I have tried copying the contents of this folder into natives depending on the current OS, still nothing. I've even setup a try/catch to check if there's an uncalled for error when I run my game window, again, nothing.

To add on, the editor has a JInternalFrame with a canvas housing the engine (for when editing) and this component does not run, it remains the white canvas.

What am I missing here? I pondered if it was a missing classpath but if it was, I would've gotten the same errors in the console. Is my application doomed to be a console only app?

For further clarification, the source is on [GitHub](http://github.com/Luigifan/JavaRPGEngine)

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming you're running it on Windows? What does the jar's manifest look like?

Comment: Also, have you considered using something like Launch4j? (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin I'm running Linux right now actually, but I have reproduced the 'error' on Windows. The manifest looks like this:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.mikesantiago.launcher.MainProgram

Could the lack of a class-path cause the error? Even after manually pointing the org.lwjgl.librarypath AND java.library.path in the program before the launch of any LWJGL componenets?

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin I will also add that on both systems (Linux and Windows) they are running Oracle Java 8, latest with all updates

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add it. I would look at that "Class-Path: ." though; is that the same one that it uses from the terminal? Because if that's wrong, then it could easily result in a false start.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin I actually don't run a classpath when I run from Terminal. I literally just put in "java -jar Launcher.jar" and it runs no problem at all, this is certainly an oddity.

Comment: re-tested under windows and found that it ran fine outside of the command line (just double clicking the jar). this is certainly an odd case, I'll have to ask my friend on OS X to check and see if he has this issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your classpath? It might help shed some light on the issue.

One thing that comes to mind is the difference in path structure between DOS-like and UNIX-like file systems.